# Check input contains HTML element on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex, entity-framework-4

I’ve created my model using Entity Framework, and I’ve created a basic website in MVC3 to allow me to edit items within the database. So far it works fine, but I wanted to add a regular expression to ensure that the contents of one of the form fields always contains a particular HTML element.

What I have in my model so far, for the property in question, is as follows:

```cs
[Required]
[AllowHtml]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
[RegularExpression("^.*(<p>).*$", ErrorMessage = "Must contain <p> element")]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

I’ve tried variations on the RegularExpression attribute shown above, but nothing seems to work. What I essentially want to do is make sure that the text in the text area for the above property always contains at least one `<p>` element.

Admittedly I’m not very strong on regular expressions, so I’m probably way off the mark. Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which makes sure that there is an opening and closing `<p>` tag (so they can't just do `<p>` without also doing `</p>`).

```
[RegularExpression(@"<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)</p>", ErrorMessage = "Must contain <p> element")]
```

There is a handy explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html), which will help you customise the example should you wish to.

Comment: Thanks. That should work, but for some reason it doesn’t. As a test, I reduced the regular expression to just `.*` and it still fails. I don’t understand what’s going on there as that should allow anything through, right?

Comment: Turns out that the problem is due to it being a multiline input field, which means that the jQuery Validation regex that is generated from the above won’t match if the code has line breaks in it. It also doesn’t like the opening `<` which is a pain to say the least. Certainly headed in the right direction though, thanks,

Comment: I missed out an @ symbol, sorry. I have edited it now and it works in a test app. Please let me know if it works - preferably by upvoting the answer if it does - ;-)